# Select() error for a data frame: object not found, but the column name exists

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I'm trying to make a function that uses `select()` and use it on a data frame `a`, but I have an error that says "object '[column name]' not found". However, when I use `colnames(a)` to see the column names I can use, it's clearly listed. Here's the code I'm using atm:

```
simplifyList <- function(x) {
    x <- x %>% {
        select(-EndDate)
    }
}

simplifyList(a)
```

I've tried using different capitalization, checking to see that `a` is of the class `data.frame`, putting `dplyr::` in front of `select()`, and updating the dplyr package, but nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The brackets around `select` are causing the problem, this works:

```
simplifyList <- function(x) {
    x <- x %>% select(-cyl)
}

colnames(simplifyList(mtcars))
 [1] "mpg"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```